# StreamZip only showing the first order stream

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use `StreamZip`, to combining 2 stream. Here is what i do

```
StreamZip([stream1, stream2]).listen((data){
  _queryController.sink.add(data);
});
```

it will send the first stream (`stream1`) only, but when i change the order to

```
StreamZip([stream2, stream1]).listen((data){
  _queryController.sink.add(data);
});
```

it will show the result of `stream2`. How can i fix it ? did i miss something?

here is the stream

```
   stream1 = databaseReference
        .collection("userChat")
        .where("from", isEqualTo: userId)
        .orderBy("messageDate", descending: true)
        .snapshots();

    stream2 = databaseReference
        .collection("userChat")
        .where('to', isEqualTo: userId)
        .orderBy("messageDate", descending: true)
        .snapshots();
```

My data

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Zip only emits a new value when there's a new pair of values from two streams (if there's a new value in the first stream, it waits for a new value in the second stream). You probably want to use `combineLatest`. It will combine values from both streams when any of them sends a new value:

```dart
final combinedStream = stream1.transform(combineLatest(stream2, (obj1, obj2) {
  // Combine both objects and return a new one
  return CombinedData(obj1, obj2);
}));
```

```dart
class CombinedData {
  final List to;
  final List from;

  CombinedData(this.to, this.from);
}
```

```
dependencies:
  stream_transform: ^0.0.2
```

Comment: Hi , can you provide me an example ? in my case, stream 1 and stream 2 are fetching result from firestore .

Comment: @MyNameIs I've updated the answer. You should merge values from both streams and return a new value in callback. I don't know anything about your data structures, so I can't tell you exactly how you want to merge it.

Comment: Ok let me try to find it on google. Btw, i have update my data screenshot

Comment: @MyNameIs Check the answer once again, please.

Comment: I get this error, `The argument type 'snapshot '  can't be assigned to the parameter type list `, should i convert it first ? because only obj1 has the error